# Read next record "NOT" previous record sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following t-sql:

```
declare @startno int = 1, @finishno int = 365, @AfterO float = 97
declare @daysbet int = 80, @decVal float = 0.10 / 100;

;with ctetest as
(
select    @startno as oDay, 1 as oBet, @AfterO as Prod
    union all
    select     oDay +1, case when ((oBet + 1) = @daysbet) then 0 else (oBet + 1) end,
    case when (Prod = 0) then @AfterO else
         case when oBet = 0 then 0 else (Prod - (@decVal * Prod)) end
    end
    from ctetest
    where oDay+1 <= @finishno
    )
    select * from ctetest option (maxrecursion 0)
```

the result is:

```
----------------------------
oDay        oBet      Prod
----------------------------
1           1         97
2           2         96.903
3           3         96.806
ff.----->
80          0         89.628
81          1         0
82          2         97
ff.----->
364         44        93.008
365         45        92.915
```

But the result that I want is not like that, the result should be like this:

---

```
oDay        oBet      Prod
----------------------------
1           1         97
2           2         96.903
3           3         96.806
ff.----->
80          0         0
81          1         97
82          2         96.903
ff.----->
364         44        92.9
365         45        92.8
```

from the formula above, it seems to be that `case when oBet = 0` read the previous record in `oBet` column. I want to read the value next to `Prod` column in `oBet` column.

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: So like `case when ((oBet + 1) = @daysbet) then 0 else (oBet + 1) end` instead of `case when oBet = 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
case when oBet = 0 then 0 else (Prod - (@decVal * Prod)) end
```

to

```
case when ((oBet + 1) = @daysbet) then 0 else (Prod - (@decVal * Prod)) end
```

Since oBet only actually becomes 0 in the next iteration (at oDay=81)